# How to pass stored variable's value to another request in jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

How can I store the value in another variable. For example if `${firstinput}` is my first variable and I want to store what ever value it contains in another variable. I would like to know how to store the value of `${firstinput}` in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the [BeanShell Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to Test Plan
2. Paste this code to BeanShell Script.

   `String whatEverValue = vars.get("firstinput");`
   `vars.put("anothervariable", whatEverValue);`

For full details on using BeanShell, please see:

- [JMeter with BeanShell Guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/)
- [BeanShell website](http://www.beanshell.org/)